# Manipulating an object tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a tiny js framework for fun, but I encountered a problem that I'm not really sure how to handle. so I want to somehow loop through these elements and basically render them as a single html element and this is how the tree looks like:

```
const tree = {
  el: "div",
  children: [
    { el: "h1", children: [{ el: "p", children: [] }] },
    { el: "h2", children: [] },
  ],
};
```

also keep in mind that i made a function called createNewElement that returns an HTMLElement where children is an array of HTMLElement:

```
createNewElement(element, attributes, ...children) : HTMLElement
```

usage:

```
const res = createNewElement('div',null,
  createNewElement('h1',null,""),
  createNewElement('h1',null,"")
);

/*
returns (<div>
             <h1></h1>
             <h1></h1>
          </div>)
*/
```

**so is there a way to convert this tree to html using this function ? like a recursive function for example ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple recursive function that recurses on all the elements of the `children` element.

```
function treeToHtml(tree) {
  return createNewElement(tree.el, tree.attributes, ...tree.children.map(treeToHtml));
}
```

Comment: sooner or later I will post an answer before you

Comment: Thank you I was missing the map function